# "TIFF file is missing a required tag StripOffsets" when working with a class "GeotiffReader"

Tags: java, tiff, geotiff, worldwind

There was such a problem: working with some * .tiff, when trying to get DataRaster [] using the readDataRaster () method in the NASA WorldWind library class GeotiffReader, an exception is thrown:

> ERROR j.l.Throwable - java.io.IOException: TIFF file is missing a
>   required tagStripOffsets

Below is the code that works with * .tiff.
Code:

```
private GeotiffReader reader;
private ByteBufferRaster raster;
...
reader = new GeotiffReader(file);
listDataRaster.add(reader.readDataRaster());
...
DataRaster[] dataRaster = listDataRaster.get(iter);
raster = (ByteBufferRaster)dataRaster[0];
...
raster.setDoubleAtPosition(y, x, value);
```

The error occurs in the line:

```
listDataRaster.add(reader.readDataRaster());
```

The method tries to return a DataRaster[] and gives the above error.

My task is to take the * .tiff ByteBufferRaster and then use setDoubleAtPosition to make changes to the grid after some calculations and rewrite * .tiff. How do I fix this error? And if not, are there other ways to accomplish my task?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! When posting exception messages like the one above, always include the full stack trace and also indicate which line the exception occurred on in the code you posted. That being said, I don't think there is a problem with your code, it's a problem with the TIFF files, they don't conform to the TIFF specification, and is missing a required tag.You might want to add (or link) the TIFF file for confirmation that this is indeed the problem.

Comment: @haraldK, the error occurs in the line:

`listDataRaster.add(reader.readDataRaster());`

The method tries to return a DataRaster[] and gives the above error

Comment: When asked for clarification, please update the question with all the necessary details. Do not answer in the comments only. A better question will help you increase the chance of getting a good answer. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, we demand to solve this way via ExtendedGDALDataRaster

```
DataRasterReaderFactory readerFactory = (DataRasterReaderFactory) WorldWind
                .createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.DATA_RASTER_READER_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME);
DataRasterReader dataRasterReader;
DataRaster[] dataRasters = null;
...
dataRasterReader = readerFactory.findReaderFor(file, null);
dataRasters = dataRasterReader.read(file, null);
...
rasterGdal = (ExtendedGDALDataRaster) dataRasters[0];

ElevationModel elevationModelFromGlobe = GLOBE.getElevationModel(); 
Sector boundingSector = rasterGdal.getSector();
int[] heightAndWidth = new int[2];  

// Method for creating an empty sector by analogy with the current one  
recalculationHeightAndWidth (boundingSector, elevationModelFromGlobe, heightAndWidth);


// Method to create default parameters for the sector
AVList params = getParams(boundingSector, heightAndWidth[1], heightAndWidth[0]);
raster = (ByteBufferRaster) ByteBufferRaster.createGeoreferencedRaster(params);

Dataset dataset = rasterGdal.getBestSuitedDataset(heightAndWidth[1], heightAndWidth[0], rasterGdal.getSector());
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1);
```

And then for you can get the value of the height of any point from * .tiff and change it to your discretion (it will be in data)

```
float[] data = new float[1];
band.ReadRaster(x, y, 1, 1, band.getDataType(), data);
```